# Why is theming not applied to custom Toolbar View?

Tags: android, xamarin

So I'm trying to create a Toolbar programmatically in Android. This toolbar and it's drawer layout goes in a fragment, which covers the entire activity layout.

I'm following this guide: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Except doing everything programmatically (without XML).

I have a custom class that inherits from Toolbar. It looks like this:

```
class MyToolbar : Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar
{
    public MyToolbar(Context context, int defStyleAttr = Resource.Style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar) : base(context, null, defStyleAttr)
    {
    }
}
```

When I initialize it with the above constructor, theming is not applied. The text is dark, the menu icon is dark, and there is no shadow and no background.

Why is theming not applied in this case? I want to use Resource.Style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar.

Comment: `defStyleAttr` isn't what you think it is. It's actually meant for a `Resource.Attribute` that has the desired `Resource.Style` set as its value in the `Context`'s theme, rather than a `Resource.Style` directly. That parameter has been confusing developers for forever. Unless you'll eventually need the `AttributeSet` parameter, you could instead use the `Context`-only constructor, and wrap the `Context` in a `ContextThemeWrapper` with the desired style in the `base` call. This is basically the same thing `Toolbar` does internally to support the `theme` attribute pre-Lollipop.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Xamarin syntax, but something like `public MyToolbar(Context context) : base(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, Resource.Style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar))`.

Comment: Thanks for the input :) Got it working! If you add an answer I will mark it as the accepted one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `defStyleAttr` parameter is slightly confusing, especially given the numerous examples out there that use it incorrectly. It's not meant to take a `Style` directly, but rather an `Attribute` that has the desired `Style` set as its value in the `Context`'s theme. This is why the `Style` is not applied in your example, as `Style`s and `Attribute`s are not interchangeable.

In this case, probably the simplest way to apply that `Style` dynamically would be to wrap the `Context` with a `ContextThemeWrapper`, and pass that in the `base` call. This is basically the same thing `Toolbar` does internally to support the `theme` attribute on `View`s for versions prior to Lollipop.

Since the `AttributeSet` parameter is not used, either, we can use the `Context`-only constructor. In Xamarin, I believe it would be something like:

```
public MyToolbar(Context context) :
    base(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, Resource.Style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Dark_ActionBar))
```